# Unable to connect to Elmah with mongoDB in webApi

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a project that is an ASP.NET WebAPI2 project that uses MongoDb to store some simple data using entity framework.  Every ASP.NET project I do I like to use ELMAH for error handling so I downloaded the MongoDB version along with the C# driver for Mongo.

When I attempt to navigate to /elmah.axd which is what the handler is told to use in the web.config I receive the following error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017

My connection string looks as follows:

```
<add name="elmah-mongodb" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/elmah?w=0" />
```

mongoDB tells me it is listening on this IP and port number.  I've tried changing my Mongod config so that it is bound to 127.0.0.1 on port 27017 even though it is the default setting.  I have not applied any permissions to mongo yet, I also tried creating the database first and that didn't work.  I've tried turning off windows firewall and anti-virus and ensured that it is allowed through on that port.  It is running the application in debug from Docker, I'm not sure if it's something to do with that.  See screenshot for full error.[image: Error]

UPDATE: Also tried starting mongod using the default settings, since I was using a config file to point the data to a different directory. also tried it using the --bind_ip_all switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  Docker does not allow you to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 since it is considered a separate instance.  You need to tell mongod to listen on another IP and use that.  If you use:

```
mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

it will listen on all available IPs on the default port of 27017.  Or you can just bind it to one of the other available IPs.

so also change your connection string to:

```
<add name="elmah-mongodb" connectionString="mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017/elmah?w=0" />
```

with the x.x.x.x being the available IP you've chosen to use.